# iOS swift data does not match cell as i scroll down

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, cell

I'm having this problem whereby when I click my ReadMore button which is prepared by segue, I got a wrong value --> cidCTV (its a ID no. in my database). There is no errors in the code, I just couldn't pass the correct value to my next controller. 
P.S. I did a println to test the value loaded in the cell and as I scroll down, the value jumped to the next before the next cell is fully view.
Is there a way to set all my value esp my cidCTV to all the cells before I start scrolling? Or could it be my storyboard alignment for the cell is wrong or something?

My struct

```
class Entry : NSObject {

var color : String = String()
var divider : String = String()
var cid : String = String()


var image : String = String()
var heading : String = String()
var title : String = String()
var desc : String = String()
}

class ChapterData : NSObject {
var newEntryArray : Array<Entry> = [];
}
```

this is my ChapterTableViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ChapterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var cidCTV : String = "";  

var pa55DB : COpaquePointer = nil
var selectStatement : COpaquePointer = nil;
var sqlString : String = "";

var arrEntryInfo : ChapterData = ChapterData()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    openDB()
    arrEntryInfo = executeSelect()

    println("Testing...")
}

func openDB() {
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    var docsDir = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("pa55.sqlite")

    if (sqlite3_open(docsDir, &pa55DB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        println("success open database")
    }
    else {
        println("failed to open database")
    }
}

func executeSelect() -> ChapterData   {
    sqlString = "SELECT * FROM Chapter where SHOW = 'true' ORDER BY CID ASC"
    var cSql = sqlString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(pa55DB, cSql!, -1, &selectStatement, nil)

    println("startment start")

    var localEntryInfo : ChapterData = ChapterData()

    while (sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        var entryInfo: Entry = Entry()

        let cid_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 0)
        var cid1 = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(cid_buf))

        let image_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 3)
        var image1 = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(image_buf))

        let heading_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)
        var heading1 = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(heading_buf))

        let title_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 2)
        var title1 = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(title_buf))

        let desc_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 4)
        var description1 = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(desc_buf))

        let divider_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 5)
        var divider1 = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(divider_buf))

        let color_buf = sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 7)
        var color1 = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(color_buf))

        entryInfo.cid = cid1!;
        entryInfo.image = image1!;
        entryInfo.heading = heading1!;
        entryInfo.title = title1!;
        entryInfo.desc = description1!;
        entryInfo.divider = divider1!;
        entryInfo.color = color1!;

        localEntryInfo.newEntryArray.append(entryInfo)
    }
    println("select statement successful executed")
    return localEntryInfo
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: navigation title

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    //navigation bar title image
    var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 32.5))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    let image = UIImage(named: "we_logo.jpg")
    imageView.image = image

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}


// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrEntryInfo.newEntryArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChapterTableViewCell

    var entry1 : Entry  = arrEntryInfo.newEntryArray[indexPath.row]

    let color : NSString = entry1.color
    cell.dividerLabel.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(color as String)

    cell.dividerLabel.text = entry1.divider
    cell.imageLabel.image = UIImage(named: entry1.image)
    cell.headingLabel.text = entry1.heading
    cell.titleLabel.text = entry1.title
    cell.descLabel.text = entry1.desc
    cell.readMoreButton.tag = (entry1.cid).toInt()!

    return cell
}

/*
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var entry1 : Entry = arrEntryInfo.newEntryArray[indexPath.row]
    cidCTV = entry1.cid
}
*/

@IBAction func shareChapter(sender: UIButton) {

    var shareChapter = "http://pa55.eu.pn/Pa55.html"

    let shareChapterC : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareChapter], applicationActivities: nil)

    self.presentViewController(shareChapterC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "ReadMoreSegue") {
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ChapterStoryController;
        println("the cid value is \(cidCTV)")
    //    svc.dataPassed = cell.readMoreButton.tag
    }
}
}
```

Comment: fyi: I want to pass the value through a button in the cell, not by selecting the row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `cidCTV = entry1.cid` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and move it into `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as below.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     var entry1 : Entry  = arrEntryInfo.newEntryArray[indexPath.row]
     cidCTV = entry1.cid
}
```

Problem is you are not updating cidTV on cell selection but at time of cell creation that will not be the correct vale. Its because, it will always has value of last created cell.

Comment: does this mean I can retrieve cidCTV value from my respective cell and pass it to another controller automatically? sorry for asking this, 'cause I'm fixing another error currently.

Comment: I just tested, it doesn't seem like I'm able to capture the cid value and put it to my prepareForSegue func, I did a println to see the value and its blank (after clicking my button).

      ` override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "ReadMoreSegue") {
            var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ChapterStoryController;
            println("\(cidCTV)")
            svc.dataPassed = cidCTV
        }
    }`